# how to use load_register in typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I begin with TYPO3 and I try to work with `LOAD_REGISTER`.

I've read multiple examples on the net and I want to try some tests but I'm not able to output the data from `LOAD_REGISTER`-variables.

Here's my code :

```
page = PAGE
page {
     count = LOAD_REGISTER
     count {
                nbblocks.cObject = TEXT
                nbblocks.cObject { 
                        data = patate
                }
     }

    10 = TEXT
    10.value = register:nbblocks
    10.wrap = <h1>|</h1>
}
```

Page only shows "register:nbblocks", which must be a basic mistake.

Thanks in advance for the help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

Firstly, the `page.count = LOAD_REGISTER` content object is not run before `page.10 = TEXT`, which means that the register you're creating is does not exist where you want to use it. This can be fixed by renaming `page.count` to `page.10` and `page.10` to `page.20`.

Secondly, you should set the `value`-key on `nnblocks.cObject` instead of the `data`-key.

Thirdly, you need to wrap registers used in the `value`-property of the `TEXT`-object in curly brackets (`{register:nbblocks}`), and lastly, you need to set `stdWrap.insertData = 1` on the `TEXT`-object.

All in all, this gives you the following code:

page = PAGE

```
page {
    10 = LOAD_REGISTER
    10 {
        nbblocks.cObject = TEXT
        nbblocks.cObject {
            value = patate
        }
    }

    20 = TEXT
    20.value = {register:nbblocks}
    20.wrap = <h1>|</h1>
    20.stdWrap.insertData = 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I needed :-)

Comment: why move the page content somewhere else, if you could use any other number lower than 10 (I also use higher than 4)?